# How to exclude Cucumber feature files

Tags: java, maven, cucumber

In cucumber tests, I want to skip some feature files without changing feature files, such as adding additional tags. Though tags can exclude feature files to run, I can't modify those files. Is there a way to configure in maven pom.xml? Or can I use @CucumberOptions with special features parameters?

Changing feature files will affect other git branches. So I want other way to exclude feature files rather than modifying feature files directly.

**One way** is to use a Maven plugin to generate a Junit Runner Class for each feature file. Then with `maven-failsafe-plugin` we can specify exclusions or inclusions to exclude or include those Junit Runner Classes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore particular scenario in cucumber?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34655222/how-to-ignore-particular-scenario-in-cucumber)

Answer (score 0):

You can tell Cucumber to ignore scenarios with a particular tag. See the [docs](https://cucumber.io/docs/cucumber/api/#ignoring-a-subset-of-scenarios).

Since that is the way to do it in Cucumber, could you explain why you are looking for a different way? What is it you are trying to accomplish?